# Add child to a layout block programmatically

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1

I want to add "children" to a given layout (custom-) block.

In my `layout-xml`:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="custom_html_blocks_body_end" as="custom_html_blocks_body_end">
    ...
    <block type="page/html" name="custom_svg_icons" as="custom_svg-icons" template="my_templates/custom_svg-icons.phtml" />
    ...
</block>
```

The block i want to add childs programmatically is `custom_svg_icons`.

In `custom_svg-icons.phtml`:

```
<?php $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

And in my script to set the children:

```
$objSVG = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setTemplate('my_templates/svg_image.phtml')->setData(array('imageName'=>'svg-image-demo'));
$objSVGBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('custom_svg-icons')->append($objSVG);
```

I get no Error, but nothing happens. There is no child.

Comment: Does your custom_svg-icons.phtml file called?

Comment: Yes. In this file is pure HTML too and rendered correctly to Output.

Comment: You should do `echo $this->getChildHtml() ` I think?

Comment: I have tried with getChild() and getChildHtml()

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that work but try

```
$objSVG = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setTemplate('my_templates/svg_image.phtml')->setData(array('imageName'=>'svg-image-demo'));

$objSVGBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('custom_svg-icons');

$objSVGBlock->setChild('svg_image',$objSVG);
```

Or might be you will need to call toHtml after set the child.

```
$objSVGBlock->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this not work. I can print the objSVG with ->toHtml directly... But not als Child from custom_svg-icons

Answer (score 1):

`getBlock()` needs the block **name** as a parameter, and that's `custom_svg_icons` in your case, not `custom_svg-icons`